# Adobe Illustrator reflect/share/link changes with another document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have like 20 smaller Ai documents each containing a specific shape... and then a main kind of "assembly" Ai document where I have all of the 20 smaller Ai documents imported into it.

What I would like to know is if there is a way to share the changes I make in the original smaller documents with the main document. For example, changing the color of one the shapes, is there any way to get the main document to reflect that change without having to manually change the color in both? Adobe Illustrator CC 2015 if it matters. Thanks.

**Edit: Nvm, solved my own problem see below.**

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have to manually update each Ai link to reflect the changes, OOPS.

Comment: Please consider slightly rephrasing your answer so it reads like a valid answer to your own question, and marking it as the accepted answer. That way, you'd have contribute to the site by writing both Q & A, Q&A-style!